# Generate a shape from a given fractal dimension in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: geometry, fractals

Let's say we have a line of unit length on the coordinate plane:

[image]

As you can see, the line touches one box on the plane (Desmos made each square on the grid $0.5$ in length). But what if we scale it up twice? That makes it touch two boxes:

[image]

The dimension of the figure is the log of the boxes touched divided by the log of the scale factor, so in this case $log_{2}(2) = 1$. If we played the same game with a square, we would get 4 boxes touched and have a dimension of $log_{2}(4) = 2$, and if we played it with a cube in 3D space, we woud get 8 cubes touched and have a dimension of $log_{2}(8) = 3$, and so on. But trying this with rough or self-embedded shapes has a different outcome. For example, take the coastline of Britain:
[image]

Assuming you had a fine enough grid, you find the dimension of the coastline tends towards about $1.21$, due to the roughness of the shape. Self-similar shapes such as a [Sierpinski triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_triangle) also have non-integer dimensions. These shapes with fractional dimensions are known as *fractals* (I reccomend you watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gB9n2gHsHN4) for a more in-depth explenation).

But my question is, can we generate fractals themselves from a given dimension? I am aware there are at least countably infinite shapes per dimension, but is it possible to sytstematically generate at least *one* example of a fractal shape for any dimension?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2636523/given-a-real-number-d-1d2-is-there-a-fractal-with-fractal-dimension-d

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Given a real number $d , (1&lt;d&lt;2)$, is there a fractal with fractal dimension $d$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2636523/given-a-real-number-d-1d2-is-there-a-fractal-with-fractal-dimension-d)

Comment: @XanderHenderson Actually, not really, but [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1714090/633945) did.